# Can't find DLL entry point OpenClipboard in User32.dll (error 453)

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10, excel-2016, user32

I am testing the below code in MSOffice Excel 2016 Pro on a windows 10 enterprise 64-bit system. I am getting the following error:

> 'Run-time error 453': Can't find DLL entry point OpenClipboard in User32.dll

[image: Runtime Error 453]

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32.dll" () As Long

Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function

Sub Test()
    Call ClearClipboard
End Sub
```

I checked any preceding folders before C:\Windows\System32 that may have a "User32.dll" that may be getting used instead of one in the default System32 folder, but couldn't find it.

Has anyone faced the same User32.dll 453 error with OpenClipboard in Excel 2016 Pro? If so, did you find any solutions?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all three functions must return `Long`.

Comment: @gserg I am on a 64-bit windows system

Comment: That does not change the size of the [`BOOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

Comment: Related to your problem, grab [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and see which user32.dll is used.

Comment: I changed the return value as Long, still doesn't work!

Comment: Like I said, it was not related to your problem, but worth fixing anyway..

Comment: In windows task manager > processes, it shows c:\windows\system32\user32.dll being used. I will check with procmon also.

Comment: no joy with procmon. It seems all Win32API code has stopped working for Excel 2016 64 bit version. I have used the correct declarations, but no clues as to why it's still giving an error.